# DMIDecode product_uuid и product_serial, в чем разница?

Tags: linux

В директории `/sys/class/dmi/id/` лежат два файла `product_uuid` и `product_serial`.

- Как эти файлы генерируются, чем отличаются?
- Каким образом они меняются?
- При переустановке системы они изменяются?
- Почему права на чтение у этих файлов есть только у `root`? У остальных файлов в этой директории есть права на чтение для всех пользователей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как эти файлы генерируются, чем отличаются?

генерируются эти псевдо-файлы кодом из файлов `dmi-id.c`, `dmi_scan.c` и `dmi-sysfs.c` из каталога [`drivers/firmware`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/firmware). содержимое берётся из bios-а в соответствии со спецификацией [smbios](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMBIOS), к [документации](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios) по которой в первую очередь и следует обращаться по поводу «что означает и чем отличается та или иная возвращаемая информация». во вторую очередь (например, если возвращаемая информация противоречит спецификации), следует обращаться к производителю bios-а и/или материнской платы.

в моей системе, например, очень сложно не заметить различий между содержимым этих двух файлов:

```
$ sudo tail /sys/class/dmi/id/product_{serial,uuid}
==> /sys/class/dmi/id/product_serial <==
System Serial Number

==> /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid <==
0F0914E0-5BCB-11D9-AE58-5404A6CC1207
```

> Каким образом они меняются?
>   При переустановке системы они изменяются?

вероятно, эту информацию можно почерпнуть из упомянутого выше описания спецификации smbios.

> Почему права на чтение у этих файлов есть только у root?

права на псевдо-файлы в обсуждаемом каталоге `/sys/class/dmi/id/` определяются в файле `dmi-id.c` с 42 по 59 строки (во втором поле в вызове макроса `DEFINE_DMI_ATTR_WITH_SHOW`). [коммит, добавивший эти строки](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/4f5c791a850e5305a5b1b48d0e4b4de248dc96f9), сделал `Lennart Poettering <mzxreary@0pointer.de>` (ага, тот самый). подробности, вероятно, можно спросить прямо у него, или в рассылке [lkml](https://lkml.org/).

> У остальных файлов в этой директории есть права на чтение для всех пользователей?

да, у большинства есть. в чём можно убедиться, и рассмотрев те самые строки (с 42 по 59), и просто выполнив:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/dmi/id/
```

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ, особенно за ссылку на  исходники по генерации этих значений.